# Whatis the pi@raspberry exactly

Tags: raspbian-stretch

When I want to connect on my raspberry with the terminal via SSH, I have to do :

```
ssh pi@raspberry
```

I know the `raspberry` is the hostname, but what is `pi@`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The format for the SSH command is:

```
ssh user@hostname
```

In this case, you're saying:

"Create an SSH session to hostname `raspberry` as user `pi`.

Comment: Ohh ok thanks ! So it's just the username ! So, I suppose that I can delete the "pi" username and create my own one with root privildge ?

Comment: Yes, you can create new users and name them whatever you want. You can also rename the "pi" account if you want, or delete it.  Be sure you create and test the new one before deleting the pi account to avoid locking yourself out.

Comment: @user676767 Please accept the answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.